# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText

Tags: android, numbers, integer

I wrote this code in order to simplify part numbers in math e.g. 2a/2b = a/b. android studio shows no problems but when i run this code:  (maz stands for lowest number, liels stands for highest number, skait is the 2a in the previous example and sauc is the 2b int the previous example, skaitout and saucout are the output text fields corresponding to the part number parts, skaitout is the top number and saucout is the bottom number)

```
package com.example.mikus.simplify;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View skait = findViewById(R.id.skait);
        View sauc = findViewById(R.id.sauc);
        TextView skaitout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.skaitout);
        TextView saucout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saucout);
        int maz;
        int liels;
        int x;
        int i = 0;
        maz = Integer.parseInt(skait.toString());
        liels = Integer.parseInt(sauc.toString());
        if(maz > liels){
            x = maz;
            maz = liels;
            liels = x;
            i = 1;
        }
        if(maz == liels){
            skaitout.setText('1');
            saucout.setText('1');
        }else{
            x = maz;
            while(true){
                if(maz % x == 0 && liels % x == 0){
                    maz /= x;
                    liels /= x;
                    x = maz;
                }else{
                    if(x == liels){
                        return;
                    }else{
                        x++;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            skaitout.setText(maz);
            saucout.setText(liels);
        }
        if(i == 1){
            skaitout.setText(liels);
            saucout.setText(maz);
        }



    }
}
```

i get the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.mikus.simplify, PID: 24905
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mikus.simplify/com.example.mikus.simplify.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{11f3506 VFED..CL. ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0057 app:id/skait}"
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{11f3506 VFED..CL. ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0057 app:id/skait}"
                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                      at com.example.mikus.simplify.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

in phone the program just crashes. can anyone help me.

Comment: Can you share your activity_main.xml? It's not clear what type of view `skait` is and if it has any default values set to it.

Answer (score 3):

You try to convert a view to string and parse this to integer:

```
liels = Integer.parseInt(sauc.toString());
maz = Integer.parseInt(skait.toString());
```

I guess you want to do something like this:

```
liels = Integer.parseInt(sauc.getText().toString());
maz = Integer.parseInt(skait.getText().toString());
```

Also, it´s possible that the user make some wrong input. You could catch the exception if the input is not a number like:

```
try{

 liels = Integer.parseInt(sauc.getText().toString());
    maz = Integer.parseInt(skait.getText().toString());

}catch(NumberFormatException ex){
 //inform the user about wrong input
}
```

or you can restrict user input to only numbers by setting this attribute to editTexts:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

And be aware: Later you will get also exceptions by setting the text:

```
  if (i == 0) {
            skaitout.setText(maz);
            saucout.setText(liels);
        }
        if(i == 1){
            skaitout.setText(liels);
            saucout.setText(maz);
        }
```

This will throw an exception, you have to cast the integer to a string like:

```
 if (i == 0) {
            skaitout.setText(Integer.toString(maz));
            saucout.setText(Integer.toString(liels));
        }
        if(i == 1){
            skaitout.setText(Integer.toString(liels));
            saucout.setText(Integer.toString(maz));
        }
```

or just for example with some quitation marks:

```
saucout.setText(""+maz);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse `View` as `int`.